# Why does it protrude when using position="fixed" at Chakra UI?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

I use Next.js and Chakra UI.

```
<Box w="100%">
```

fits in the screen, but

```
<Box w="100%" position="fixed">
```

protrudes the screen.

Why does it protrude when using position="fixed"?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you use fixed || absolute, Stacking Order Context rebuilt. Also, normally fixed & absolute option makes DOM object independently. I think that your component which is updated `position : fixed` is at the top of the screen. You can figure it out set width & height to that.